What is a Barbecuǝ Phrase™?
This puzzle continues the tradition of What is a Word/Phrase puzzles begun by JLee

If a phrase conforms to a special rule, I call it a Barbecuǝ Phrase™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.



Barbecuǝ Phrase™
Non-Barbecuǝ Phrase™




Patiram is situated beside of Atreyee River
Lawrence River is low


Opuntia Basilaris blooms from spring to early summer
The atomic number uniquely identifies a chemical element


The lock's wooden gates are no longer extant
A boomerang is a curved wooden throwing implement


Senate race to Douglas
Executive power is exercised by the government


Many lands are being irrigated through these streams
It defends a linear territory along streams


The station features programming from Citadel Media
Its programming includes films, documentaries, and talk shows


Francis Medical Center, Hartford, Connecticut
Alabama's capital is Montgomery


Lawes advocating the inmates' mutual welfare league
The prison guards were overtaken and inmates escaped


Donatella is an italian feminine given name
Belladonna is an italian rock noir band


Data for union territories are not available
Customs unions are established through trade pacts


He was also an amateur architect
He is also the patron of the Augustinians



CSV:
Patiram is situated beside of Atreyee river;Lawrence River is lowOpuntia Basilaris blooms from spring to early summer;The atomic number uniquely identifies a chemical elementThe lock's wooden gates are no longer extant;A boomerang is a curved wooden throwing implementSenate race to douglas;Executive power is exercised by the governmentMany lands are being irrigated through these streams;It defends a linear territory along streamsThe station features programming from Citadel Media;Its programming includes films, documentaries, and talk showsFrancis Medical Center, Hartford, Connecticut;Alabama's capital is MontgomeryLawes advocating the inmates' mutual welfare league;The prison guards were overtaken and inmates escapedDonatella is an italian feminine given name;Belladonna is an italian rock noir bandData for union territories are not available;Customs unions are established through trade pactsHe was also an amateur architect;He is also the patron of the Augustinians
Hint 1:

 Reverse

Hint 2:

 Don't discard the original

Hint 3:

 {Word associated with barbecue} -> Homophone

Hint 4:

 Spaces are very important


Note: The phrases themselves do not require knowledge

"Patiram is situated beside of Atreyee River" sounds incorrect. Shouldn't it be" Patiram is situated beside the Atreyee River" ?

@JLee All phrases were taken from Wikipedia, so an edit might be necessary in the Patiram article. Swapping "of" with "the" would break the rule, so I'll leave it as it is either way.

And the phrase before the "Opuntia basilaris" one contains the word "barbed". I'm begining to think that's a red herring ...

A Barbecuǝ Phrase™ is a phrase ...

 ... that encodes an English word by taking the letters at the positions of the spaces when counting backwards from the end.

To illustrate:

 The first letter of the word encoded in the first phrase is the "a" at position six, because the last space in that phrase is before the five-letter word "river". (Something interesting to note is that none of the phrases have a terminating punctuation, even if they form full sentences.)

 The words that are encoded in the Barbecuǝ Phrases™ are:

Patiram is situated beside of Atreyee river
revir eeyertA fo ediseb detautis si maritaP
     a       t  t      i        r  e

Opuntia Basilaris blooms from spring to early summer
remmus ylrae ot gnirps morf smoolb siralisaB aitnupO
      a     l  i      m    o      n         y

The lock's wooden gates are no longer extant
tnatxe regnol on era setag nedoow s'kcol ehT
      c      o  n   t     e      n      t

Senate race to douglas
salguod ot ecar etaneS
       r  e    d

Many lands are being irrigated through these streams
smaerts eseht hguorht detagirri gnieb era sdnal ynaM
       n     e       i         t     h   e     r

The station features programming from Citadel Media
aideM ledatiC morf gnimmargorp serutaef noitats ehT
     t       e    e           n        i       e

Francis Medical Center, Hartford, Connecticut
tucitcennoC ,droftraH ,retneC lacideM sicnarF
           i         r       o       n

Lawes advocating the inmates' mutual welfare league
eugael eraflew lautum 'setamni eht gnitacovda sewaL
      a       n      i        m   a          l

Donatella is an italian feminine given name
eman nevig eninimef nailati na si alletanoD
    t     i        l       i  n  g

Data for union territories are not available
elbaliava ton era seirotirret noinu rof ataD
         u   n   r           e     a   l

He was also an amateur architect
tcetihcra ruetama na osla saw eH
         s       a  u    c   e


Why is it called a Barbecuǝ Phrase™?

 The way the word is encoded could be considered a grille cipher: The spaces in the phrase are used as the windows where the letters are read off after rotating the grille. The rotation about 180° is indicated by the rotated letter e. (Says Stiv, who apparently knows about such things.)


Aha, well found :) I got stuck on thinking the BBQ-related connection was rot13(Fnhpr, naq guhf Fbhepr, naq fcrag n ybg bs gvzr ybbxvat ng gur bevtvany Jxxv cntrf! V abgr gubhtu gung 'fnhpr' qbrf vaqrrq srngher nf lbhe ynfg jbeq, juvpu vf avpr. Gur OOD jbeq lbh jnag gubhtu vf 'tevyy' - ybbx hc tevyyr pvcuref...).

Ah, nice solve! And a cool cipher/puzzle
